Does inflation imply the existence of dark energy?
One of the few things we know for certain about our universe is that the current rate of expansion equals its average rate of expansion. We know this because the reciprocal of today's Hubble constant equals the current age of the universe. This can be seen by the dotted line in the diagram. But if the expansion of the universe starts off faster than the average rate, inflation, then it must slow down. If the expansion slows down to the average rate we will get the green line. The universe will be bigger than it really is. The expansion can slow down for longer, the blue line, until the universe is the correct size, but then the expansion rate will be slower than the average rate, the current rate. The only way the rate can slow down to match both the actual size and the average, the current, rate, is if it slows down even faster and then speeds up again, rather like landing a plane, the red line. But this accelerating expansion will require dark energy. So it seems like dark energy is a necessity if inflation is to occur. We can't have one without the other.


"the reciprocal of today's Hubble constant equals the current age of the universe" -- This is not correct. $H_0^{-1}$ gives you an order of magnitude estimate of the age of the Universe, and sometimes in popular articles people will describe $H_0^{-1}$ as the age of the Universe to avoid getting too technical, but to compute the actual age you need to do an integral over the expansion history. Physics does not constrain the average expansion rate.

You are of course correct, but does this significantly affect the question?

@Andrew. I mean the reciprocal of the Hubble constant seems at least rather close to the best estimates of the current age of the universe. Surely better than an order of magnitude.

Hi John. Perhaps you can look at it like this: the Universe is a computation that is increasing in optimality, resulting in length dilation.

The premise of your question seems to be that there must be some "compensation" between the expansion rate during inflation and the current expansion rate. What I'm saying is that there is no mechanism that enforces this, which seems to undermine the premise of your question, unless I've misunderstood. It might not even be true that $H_0^{-1}$ is close to the age of the Universe -- if eternal inflation is correct, the Universe might be much older than the age predicted by the $\Lambda$CDM model.

@Andrew. The reciprocal of the Hubble constant doesn't have to equal the age of the universe, it is just that observationally it seems to be very close. Doesn't this make the question valid?

@JohnHobson I don't think that's a good argument because two things can be numerically close observationally without being related. But even beside that, even that statement isn't correct, because we don't observe the age of the Universe. We infer it, assuming the $\Lambda$CDM model, with parameters fixed by observation. Like I said, the actual age of the Universe could actually be much larger than the $\Lambda$CDM model predicts, and we would have no idea, at least with our current level of knowledge.

This question seems to be asking that if we have the requirement that the universe is expanding as fast as we observe it to be today (yellow circle), and we have the requirement that the universe went through inflation (orange circle), then there must be a time when the universe's expansion slowed down followed by and accelerated (red line), ergo, dark energy exists.
The problem with that train of reasoning is that it's circular. We know the universe is expanding at the current rate because we observe it, but we didn't observe inflation; we deduce inflation happened via assuming the Lambda-CDM model, then ... - and by assuming the Lambda-CDM model, we've assumed dark energy exists. Conversely, if one of the many modified theories of gravity turn out to be true, then dark energy might not exist, whereupon inflation also might not have happened. Therefore, the question "does inflation imply the existence of dark energy?" is ill-posed.


So the high initial rate of expansion at this scale is not inflation, but is it a consequence of inflation?

@JohnHobson I don't understand your comment. What is "this scale"?

The scale of the diagram. Inflation will not show up on any diagram like this. All diagrams (popular at least) of an expanding universe show the initial rate of expansion to be greater than the average rate. This is not inflation but is it a consequence of inflation.

@Profrob. In many images of the expanding universe, the current rate of expansion is very similar to the average rate. But more importantly, the data of Perlmutter et al, based on standard candles, show the expansion rate of the universe asymptotically approaching the average rate of expansion.

@JohnHobson you can certainly show it, but you'd need logarithmic scales.

There is both a nomenclature problem and a circular reasoning problem in your question.
The nomenclature issue is that "inflation" is not shown on your diagram. It is inferred to take place in the first tiny fraction of a second. The exponential increase of the scale factor (your y-axis) that happens in that tiny fraction of a second is indeed attributed to some sort of "dark energy" or inflationary potential.
The initial, faster expansion shown in your diagram is not due to dark energy and dark energy is negligible in the early evolution of $\Lambda$CDM universes. In all your curves, the curvature indicating a negative second derivative are epochs where the universe is decelerating. Only the reversal to a positive curvature in the red curve would indicate an increasing importance of dark energy.
The circular reasoning is that we don't measure the age of the universe (although we can measure lower limits), we infer it from a model after measuring the cosmological parameters.
Prior to the discovery of the accelerating expansion and the concordance $\Lambda$CDM model, it was thought we lived in a roughly flat universe or slightly open universe with an age of about $2H_0^{-1}/3$. This was a "crisis" in cosmology because the oldest stars appeared to be older than the universe. The discovery of acceleration (your red curve) solved that problem, because the age of the universe is now approximately $H_0^{-1}$.
A couple of additional things. The age of the universe now is estimated to be $\simeq H^{-1}$. However, $H$ is decreasing to an asymptotic value. The rough equality between the age and $H^{-1}$ is only true now, not in the past or the future. There is likely an anthropic argument why we observe this to be the case - time for structure to emerge, lifetime of stars etc. Second, your graph is incorrect. The different coloured curves should start from different points in the past along the time axis. The red curve first, then the green, then the blue.
